# Git log path parameter seems to prevent saving output into a file

Tags: git, shell, alias

I find the `git log` functionality to be clunky at best in both the command line and GUIs I've tried, so I'm trying to write a git alias that will get the diff history of a file and open it in a text editor (so it's easier for me to read through quickly).

So far, I've written the following alias:

```
[alias]
    trace = "!f() { NOW=$(date +"%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S"); FILE="~/Documents/git-traces/file_diff_$NOW.txt"; > $FILE; git --no-pager log -p --follow --pretty=oneline -- $1 > $FILE; 'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe' $FILE; }; f"
```

Without the `-- $1` parameter, the alias works great -- it runs the `git log` command just fine and stores the output in the generated file.

Also, the command works fine when I leave the output in the console -- it displays what I want without a problem.

But, with both `-- $1` and `> $FILE` in there, the file ends up empty.

Does anyone know why these parameters don't seem to work together? Any ideas to make it work?

I haven't really done much shell scripting before, so let me know if I've just made a newb mistake :)

EDIT: I'm using msysgit v1.8.4 on WIndows 7, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Does your file name have spaces in it? If so, your function should use `"$1"` instead of just `$1`... It probably should, anyway... Do you pass a full path or a relative path or just a single file name?

Comment: perhaps the inner double quotes is the problem. Try changing the outer quotes to single quotes.

Comment: @glenn the inner double quote was my first thought, too, but I have another alias with the same format that works fine -- the only difference between the two is the `git log` command. I tried changing the quotes anyway, but I think it just caused other problems.... so I changed it back.

Comment: Oh, and @twalberg, the file name doesn't have spaces in it, but I hadn't considered that possibility. I'll change that -- thanks for finding a future bug for me :). So far I've been passing in a relative path: `./docroot/WEB-INF/portlet.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Git starts the shell in a [POSIX mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html), so the tilde expansion is not what you might expect it to be:

> Tilde expansion is only performed on assignments preceding a command name, rather than on all assignment statements on the line.

Use `$HOME` instead of the `~` tilde. And give this short example a test drive,

```
$ git config alias.trace '!f(){F="$HOME/file_diff_$(date+"%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S")"; git --no-pager log -p --follow --pretty=oneline -- "$@" > $F; head $F; }; set -x; f'
```

Remove the `set -x` after you are satisfied that all the commands are as expected.

Comment: No dice. Tried setting it on command line and writing it manually in my global `.gitconfig` file. Seems to be having problems with nested quotes maybe?
In any case, I don't think the tilde is the problem -- the file gets created just fine, and even opens like I want. It's just doesn't have the output of the `git log` command for some reason...

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation on using `$HOME` though -- I guess I'll use that instead of `~` to make things a little clearer. My original issue still stands, though :/

Comment: That command that I posted works verbatim in my bash shell,  no nested quotes issues. Anyway, can you post the output with `set -x` enabled as I suggested?

Comment: After pasting that command in verbatim and calling the function, I get:
`f(){F="$HOME/file_diff_$(date+"%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S")"; \
    git --no-pager log -p --follow --pretty=oneline -- "$@" > $F; head $F; }; \
set -x; f: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token '{F="$HOME/file_diff_$(date+"%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S")"'
f(){F="$HOME/file_diff_$(date+"%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S")"; \
git --no-pager log -p --follow --pretty=oneline -- "$@" > $F; head $F; }; \
    set -x; f: -c: line 0: 'f(){F="$HOME/file_diff_$(date+"%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S")"; \'`

Sorry for the poor formatting, can't seem to get it very pretty...

Comment: @EthanBustad Apologies, seems line breaks has gone awry. Just use it as one long command - I've edited the answer.

Comment: Still getting the same error :/. If it makes a difference, I'm using msysgit v1.8.4 -- I'll add that in to my original post.